# How to create group in whatsapp application in android programatically?

Tags: java, android, sms, whatsapp

I want to create whatsapp group by programmatically in my application. How to create group of contacts & how to send text message & images in group of whatsapp?? Please suggest me.

Comment: I doubt you can do anything in others application. If **API** is available, then you may achieve it

Comment: @Nabin i know that r8 now this not possible, but if API or any solution given by whatsapp. because in developer site we can access facebook, linkedin , google plus.

Comment: Show what you have done till now

Comment: @Nabin i havent done. I want to create group contact in whats app.